# Why there is a part of the code who is not executed? Node.js/Oriento

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientdb, oriento

I have call a function, `function select(items ,className, callback)` ,which have inside a console.log `console.log("Function ran.")` and the **console.log** is never made.

Here I called it:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('User connected.');

  openServer();  //This start the connection between OrientDB and the Server

  select("name", "Buyers", function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log("ERROR: ", err);
    } else {
      console.log("result from db is: ", data);
    }
  });
```

Code of the function:

```
function select(items ,className, callback){

    server.query("SELECT "+items+" FROM "+className+"", function(err, result){
      console.log("Function ran.");
      if (err) 
        return callback(err, null);
      else
        return callback(null, result[0].name);
    });
  }
```

Neither of `console.log()` of the `select function()` are executed.

My question is:

- Why does they never get executed?

Comment: select will not get called until the `io.on('connection'` callback function is triggered - so the only issue is, that you never get a connection happening

Comment: is code in "openServer" is asynchronous?

Comment: when you say "Neither of console.log() are executed", you mean none of the four in the code you posted?

Comment: I mean the `console.log` on the `function select`

Comment: so `'User connected.'` is output?

Comment: Yes, all my code is executed except `function select()`

Comment: try moving the console.log up, so it is the first line inside the function - does it work then?

Comment: is code in openServer asyncrhonous ... i.e. how is `server` initialised

Comment: `Neither of console.log() of the select function()` - there is only one console.log in the select function ... there are two in the callback called by the select function

Comment: The server is initialized using server.open . (Yes, server is the name of the var, `var server = new OrientDB({ etc..`)  I can make **Insert** successfully.

Comment: Neither the `console.log()` of the **callback** or of the **select function()**

Comment: if you put a console.log after the openServer but before the select, does it get exectued? and also another console.log as the first line in select 9as suggested by @laney earlier

Comment: Yes, it does get executed.

Answer (score 2):

OrientJS as the old Oriento uses Promises

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientJS-Query.html